# Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument when running chisq.test

Tags: r

I am importing an excel file and trying to run chisq.test on it but keep getting the following error:  Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
Below is what it looks like in the console.  Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix this error?

```
M <- read_excel("~/Desktop/M1.xlsx")
M
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  
Location          S     R
  
<chr>           <dbl> <dbl>
1 ShadysidePark    37    11
2 SilverCreek      37    11
chisq.test(M, correct=T)
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument



I assume it may have something to do with the <chr> or <dbl> labels

M <- read_excel("~/Desktop/M1.xlsx")
M
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  
Location          S     R
  
<chr>           <dbl> <dbl>
1 ShadysidePark    37    11
2 SilverCreek      37    11
chisq.test(M, correct=T)
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Answer (score 1):

The first column is character.  We may remove that column and do the test

```
chisq.test(M[-1], correct = TRUE)
```

---

According to `?chisq.test`

> x- a numeric vector or matrix. x and y can also both be factors.

Here, the data showed is a tibble with first column as character.  We remove the first column and apply the chisq.test.  Although, it is mentioned as `matrix`, it still works with `tibble`